# Removing author base slug in WordPress without having to loop through all users

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

Default author links in WordPress look like this `example.com/author/bobama`. I am using the following 2 functions which remove the base slug `/author/` making author links look like `example.com/bobama`.

```
function my_remove_author_base_function() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->author_base = '';
    $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/%author%';
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_remove_author_base_function' );
```

--

```
function author_base_rewrite_rules_function( $author_rewrite ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Reset the author rewrite rules
    $author_rewrite = array();

    // Grab the user_nicename column
    $authors = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT user_nicename FROM {$wpdb->users}" );

    // Loop through every user and create corresponding rewrite rules
    foreach( $authors as $author ) {
        $author_rewrite["({$author})/page/?([0-9]+)/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
        $author_rewrite["({$author})/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]';
    }

    // Return new rewrite rules
    return $author_rewrite;
}
add_filter( 'author_rewrite_rules', 'author_base_rewrite_rules_function' );
```

Is there a way to remove the base slug `/author/` without having to loop through all of the users? I have lots of users on my site and looping through them slows things down.

Comment: After a quick google search I think your best bet would be caching the array.

Comment: Would that cause problems for new users signing up?

Comment: Yes, but I think if you would only cache for 30 seconds or so it would not be a problem. Otherwise you could overwrite the default Wordpress functions for users signing up, changing usernames (if that is even possible) etc. to delete/regenerate the cache. See here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache

Comment: how about if I run the loop on a certain role only - say 'subscribers'. So when a user signs up, they're given the role subscriber. Then filter the author rewrite rules. Then once that is done I'll change the user's role to something else. That way the loop run on a handful of users (subscribers) at the very most because most users on the site would have been moved over to a different role. Would this approach work?

Comment: I'll answer in some pseudo-code how I'd do it below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I said something about pseudo code but I found it should actually be quite easy.

So here is how I'd do it:

```
function author_base_rewrite_rules_function( $author_rewrite ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Check cache and return if exists
    // get_transient returns FALSE if the key is not set or is expired
    if(($author_rewrite = get_transient('author_rewrite')) !== FALSE) {
        return $author_rewrite;
    }

    // Reset the author rewrite rules
    $author_rewrite = array();

    // Grab the user_nicename column
    $authors = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT user_nicename FROM {$wpdb->users}" );

    // Loop through every user and create corresponding rewrite rules
    foreach( $authors as $author ) {
        $author_rewrite["({$author})/page/?([0-9]+)/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
        $author_rewrite["({$author})/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]';
    }

    // Set cache for one hour
    set_transient('author_rewrite', $author_rewrite, 60 * 60); 

    // Return new rewrite rules
    return $author_rewrite;
}

add_filter( 'author_rewrite_rules', 'author_base_rewrite_rules_function' );
```

Then for the user user registration you create a hook:

```
function clear_author_rewrite_rules( $user_id = NULL) {
    delete_transient('author_rewrite');
}

add_action('user_register', 'clear_author_rewrite_rules');
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. is there a downside to setting the cache for longer than 1 hour? I'm assuming the only time the cache needs to be updated is when a new user registers?

Comment: No, there is not really a downside, but I see no reason to keep it longer than that, I also don't see a reason to not keep it longer than that. By the way. I read that the `WP_Object_Cache` does not have a persistent cache (anymore). But I found this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API I'll change my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Good point - i was thinking about persistent cache too. when a user visits a new page the loop will need to be re-run.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a test run and report back. One thing - i notice you've set the expiration to 1 hour. Can this be extended? Ideally no expiry would be the best way to go - i think the transient needs to be updated only at the point when the `user_register` hook runs?

Comment: Yeah sure, just put `60 * 60 * 24 * <n Days you wish to cache>` up there. There HAS to be an expiry time though. Even if you set it to 10 years. It'll probably never reach that point anyway. (10 years would be `60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10`)

Comment: Right! i'll set one way into the future. I noticed after reading http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API that transients may expire before their expire due to database upgrades etc but i can see if `get_transient` returns false, a new one will be created because `set_transient` will be allowed to run

Comment: Yeah I would not worry too much about the logic running from time to time when not intended. I agree it would be a waste to let it run on every request but I don't think it would be a problem if it ran a few times more. Furthermore I'd feel more confortable that if, for whatever reason, bad data was generated, it would have another shot in an hour or so.

Comment: good point about bad data - Every hour is reasonable, doubt very much that would impact performance. One thing I have noticed during testing just now - when a new user signs up and visits their profile page `example.com/henrywright` they get a 404

Comment: Is the `clear_author_rewrite_rules` function run properly? E.g. log something or put an exception there to be sure.

Comment: If you are working with a plugin class be sure to: `add_action( 'user_register', array( $this, 'clear_author_rewrite_rules' ) );`

Comment: Using `flush_rewrite_rules` inside `clear_author_rewrite_rules` avoids getting the 404 on new user sign up. I don't understand why `delete_transient` doesn't do the same thing. Unless `set_transient` isn't working for some reason to begin with? i'm confused :(

Comment: have you tried it? I'd be interested to know it if works for you?

Comment: I have no Wordpress installation, I drew on my ability to read documentation and a basic understanding of how most frameworks/CMSs work :) WP might cache its rewrite rules anyway and flushing them forces a recreation of those rules. Just a wild guess. Glad you could get it to work! Your solution is not a problem in either case, if WP caches it the caches have to be recreated. The rewrite rules might be generated before the hook is called and they'd have to be flushed and recreated. EDIT: they are probably cached: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules our cache might be overkill

Comment: `set_transient` doesn't seem to fire at all actually. I just checked the `wp_options` table and the `author_rewrite` transient doesn't get inserted.

Comment: Think the problem is the `author_rewrite_rules hook`. It seems to fire only when rewrite rules are refreshed. so if the `author_rewrite` transient is removed from the database for whatever reason and then a user registers, they'll get the 404 - unless of course rewrite rules are flushed at the point of registration.

Comment: By extension on my last comment - if `author_rewrite_rules` runs only on refreshing rewrite rules, then perhaps the loop won't impact performance very much. And furthermore, setting a transient isn't actually needed? grateful if you could let me know your thoughts on this? Thanks for all your help - wouldn't have got to this point without your help.

Comment: Yes, just remove the `get/set_transient` stuff and just call the flush rules function, then it'll be fine. ;)